# Нужно ли выделять запятыми? Требуются ли они тут?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, авторская-пунктуация

Что-то меня переклинило. Нужны ли тут запятые, требуется ли выделять "за то, что ты быстро выполнил эту работу"?

*Если сможешь сегодня закончить работу, то ты получишь от меня благодарность, а также мою бонусную плату тебе за качественно выполненную работу. К тому же(,) **за то, что ты быстро выполнил эту работу**(,) ты можешь рассчитывать на получение следующих заказов.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***К тому же(,)** за то, что ты быстро выполнил эту работу, ты можешь рассчитывать на получение следующих заказов.*

Со второй запятой всё понятно: она нужна (закрывает придаточное предложение). А вот постановка первой запятой, как я думаю, зависит от авторского решения.

С одной стороны, в справочнике по пунктуации ([Грамота.ру](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/k-tomu-zhe)) пишут: «После слов «к тому же» запятая не ставится». Но с другой стороны, сочетание ***к тому же*** можно заменить синонимом [***кроме того/этого***](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/krome-togo-etogo), а это уже вводное сочетание.

**Советы преподавателей** ([источник](https://www.kp.ru/edu/shkola/k-tomu-zhe-zapyataya/)):

> В романе «Идиот» есть такое предложение с обособлением: «К тому же, вы сейчас как начнете рассказывать, перестанете быть философом». По правилам обособлять такие конструкции не нужно, однако если автор текста хочет «к тому же» выделить интонационно, подчеркнуть значимость информации, подаваемой с помощью этого сочетания, то он может выделить его и запятыми или поставить одну запятую после сочетания, если оно употребляется в начале предложения.

Comment: @Sharon Так и знал, что вы скажете о двух паузах :))  Нет, не смущает: второй паузы может и не быть, даже наверняка не будет, если мы делаем первую паузу. ***За то, что*** читается в один присест, запятая чисто грамматическая. // Авторское понимание никто не отменяет. // Непонятно, какое вводное слово перед присоединительным союзом? Союз ***к тому же*** заменяем на вводное ***кроме того***. // Ударения: *К томУ же, за то, что ты бЫстро выполнил эту работу...*

Comment: @Sharon Во-первых, я не против варианта без запятой, я против однозначного решения. Во-вторых, грамматич. запятую я не отменяю (сколько было сказано о том, что запятые и паузы далеко не всегда совпадают). В-третьих, я тоже за правила, и предисловие Розенталя о вариативности и многогранности русской пунктуации, которое вы неоднократно приводили, помню хорошо. И не в моей компетенции ставить лингвистов на место.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

*К тому же за то, **что ты быстро выполнил эту работу**, ты можешь рассчитывать на получение следующих заказов.*

Это СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным** (вмещающий тип), союз ***ЧТО***. Придаточное находится в **середине** предложения.  Присоединительный союз **к тому же** относится к указательному местоимению ***за то*** в главной части СПП.

[К ТОМУ ЖЕ, союз](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/k-tomu-zhe)

Присоединительные обороты, начинающиеся союзом «к тому же», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. После слов «к тому же» запятая **не ставится.**

Answer (score 1):

```
 Правила в русском языке по своей строгости приближаются к 
 юридическим законам. А как любили повторять еще 
 древнеримские юристы, «закон суров, но – закон!»
```

1. Может ли присоединительный союз использоваться в качестве  **вводного слова?**  Закон не разрешает!  А если **договориться** с законом?..

Вот Достоевский в романе "Идиот" обособил вводное слово. **Великим** все можно? Да ладно, чего там, в наше время тоже обособляют.

**В чем же дело?** Вводное слово не часть речи, а функция. А союз этот — не союз, а скорее союзное **соединение**, так что выделить его ударением не так сложно, особенно в начале предложения. Со **структурой и грамматикой** договорились, осталась **семантика.** Да и там все нормально: способ оформления речи, используется  в значении "кроме того". Просто братья-близнецы!

Итак, вот предложение у Достоевского: ***К томУ же,** / вы сейчас как **начнЕте** рассказывать, // перестанете быть **филОсофом**.*

Да, в первой фразе *к тому же* было бы лишним, а так все гармонично. Так это же **Достоевский!**

2. А вот наше предложение: ***К тому же, за тО,** // что ты быстро выполнил эту **рабОту,** // ты можешь рассчитывать на получение следующих **закАзов**.*

Что тут скажешь? При наличии обособления графика нехороша, произношение неясное. Произносительную паузу после ***к тому же*** мы и так делаем, а теперь вот запятой обозначили. **А оно того стоило?**

**Примечание.**  Кстати, стилистика предложения не идеальна, повтор *ты* например. Если уж с ним работать, то надо отнестись к этому серьезно. Может, и структуру надо перестраивать. Надо сказать, что **наличие** разных вариантов произношения – это уже признак **отсутствия** гармонии.

3. **Примеры из Нацкорпуса** (их мало)

Вероятно, присоединительный союз обособляется, если  **плохо вписывается** в структуру предложения по различным причинам (структура, семантика). Тогда оно и напоминает **вводное слово**, которое членом предложения не является.

***К тому же,** в отличие от нас он успел прославиться.*

***К тому же,** финансовые потоки, образуемые переводами мигрантов, очень стабильны.*

***К тому же,** когда это случается, результат не впечатляет: в Воронеже, на Ставрополье, да и почти везде поддержанные Церковью кандидаты проигрывали.*